# Differences in the Java and web browsers display colors

Tags: java, colors, web

So I understand that there is a difference between the way web browsers show colors, but I am just wondering why there is a difference between how Java displays colors and web browsers do and if there is a way to correct for this in a java program.

My specific instance:

From this page:
http://xkcd.com/color/rgb/

I am using the color 'periwinkle'.  It is RGB value #8e82fe.

When building a java application (high level description, colored objects being shown for an experiment), the color is not the same it was on the web.

Is there a way to correct for this in the code?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the colors side-by-side and what code you are using to set it in Java?

Comment: That XKCD chart was made by asking 500000 people to click in a color picker on what they think is "periwinkle" then averaging things out. It has nothing to do with system-defined colour names. That said, the RGB colour `#8e82fe` should display the same when rendered by Java or from a web page stylesheet. (Colour profiles notwithstanding, but those shouldn't be involved in this case.)

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication.  The 'name' of the color is arbritrary - we chose it for other reasons.  Also, I am displaying the colors in java using Java.awt.Color by doing "new Color(0x8e82fe)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use XKCD for your comparisons. Reading into the background behind that page ( see [here](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/03/01/color-name-survey/) and [here](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) ) that the experiment has nothing to do with what the actual color is, but what people think the name of the color is.

If your RGB colors are not matching out, then something is (probably) wrong in your code. Try adding an FF as the front (switching it to ARGB) and see if that resolves the problem.

Also, if you get IE, Firefox and Chrome ( I happen to have all of them at work ) and put the same web page in, and compare them, they *should* look the same ( they do to me, anyways... ).

Comment: Using the alpha bits (so going from "new Color(0x8e82fe)" to "new Color(0xFF8e82fe, true") made it more true to the color on the webpage.  Thank you!

Also, I may have miscommunicated the original question.  The term "periwinkle" had nothing to do with the differences between viewing the RGB hex value in a web browser vs viewing it through Java.awt.Color

Comment: @bcmcmahan Noted. It _is_ a hilarious webcomic, and there have been a couple of questions that took a bit too seriously. Question was a bit strange, but with that bit of knowledge it makes bunches of more sense. Glad you found an answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to [XKCD's survey](http://xkcd.com/color/rgb/), most of those people think periwinkle averages out to #8e82fe.

While the color lovers website tends to think of periwinkle as #8480d9.

According to [Decimal Color codes](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colordec.html), periwinkle is defined to be #aaaaff.

The [web color version](http://www.colorcombos.com/colors/CCCCFF) of Periwinkle resolves to #ccccff.

Of course, that's not accounting for the [various tones of periwinkle](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periwinkle_%28color%29).

You're probably not comparing the same colors to begin with.

Comment: I'm actually comparing the RGB hexes.  Apologies for the miscommunication. Updated the original post with a comment.